# How do I use ":" in XML element names using lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

How do I generate and parse XML like the following using `lxml`?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="a" xmlns:a="http_//www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
....
</s:Envelope>
```

I currently swap : with _ in the element names when I parse and generate XML, but it seems stupid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're asking, but maybe this will help:

An element such as `<s:Envelope>` is using a XML namespace prefix.  This is used to indicate that the `s:Envelope` attribute in this document is defined in the `a` namespace.

LXML represents XML namespaces using a namespace prefix in braces, for example: `{a}Envelope`.  Your example document is sort of confusing, because you also defined the `a:` namespace prefix, so:

- `a:Element` is equivalent to `{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Element`, and
- `s:Element` is equivalent to `{a}Element`.

Many of the LXML commands let you provide a namespace prefix mapping.  For example, to find the `Envelope` element in your document using XPATH, you could do this:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
doc = etree.parse('mydocument.xml')
envelope = doc.xpath('//s:Envelope',
  namespaces={'s': 'a'})
```

Note that this is exactly equivalent to:

```
envelope = doc.xpath('//x:Envelope',
  namespaces={'x': 'a'})
```

That is, the namespace *prefix* doesn't have to match what is used in the source XML document; only the the absolute namespace matters.

You can read more about LXML and namespaces [here](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces).